Error upgrading ubuntu (running ZFS) from 22.04 to 24.04: /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_blabla'
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, with ZFS, and wish to upgrade to the newest LTS which is currently 24.04.1.
I did
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

in the hope of later doing sudo do-release-upgrade;
but the sudo apt upgrade stopped with
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_p78auf'.

I googled that error message and eventually got to this page on a Mint forum that said

There seems to be an issue with how Ubuntu is managing HWE kernels and ZFS

In my case I do have ZFS on the system I wish to upgrade but I am fine with a regular kernel: I don't need an HWE one. I tried the instructions on this blog post pointed to by the Mint forum, but they led nowhere. I undid the changes, since they were for "zfsutils-linux and HWE Kernels" and didn't work.
How do I overcome that error and upgrade to 24.04?
